# DB2 backup and restore db table preserving foreign key constraints

Tags: reference, foreign-keys, db2, backup, restore

I'm currently having issue going through a test backup and restore of database table on my development machine for db2. Was never entirely successful. Although I was able to restore all data after a drop and re-create of the table, I wasn't able to reset the foreign key constraint as I got SQL error complaining that keys don't match. Here's my exact steps, I'm sure not entirely the right way to do it, but it does eventually restore the 5423 rows of data:

The process

1. export to /export/home/dale/comments.ixf of ixf messages /export/home/dale/msg.txt select * from .comments

   Note: step 1 exports 5423 rows of data to a location
2. drop table .comments
3. import from /export/home/dale/comments.ixf of ixf create into .comments

   Note: step 3 here creates the table but does not insert any data rows
4. load client from /export/home/dale/comments.ixf of ixf modified by identityoverride replace into .comments

   Note: up until this step, I'm able to insert the 5423 rows of data in the recreated db table
5. alter table .comments add FOREIGN KEY (comments_id) REFERENCES .news (article_key)

   Note: here alter table fails as db2 complaints that some comments_id does not match article_key

Could anyone help with my problem here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really answering your question, but why are you doing a "backup and restore" using export? An export is not really a backup.

Comment: Hi Matthew, it's really a backup of a table not the entire db. This is just my approach to this, which I won't think it's the proper way of doing it. However, I'm pretty confident that there will be a more proper way in db2 to backup and restore on a table level, but don't know what is it. Cheers

Comment: Please post the actual error message you get from Step #5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that some of the rows you IMPORT into the Comments table refer to rows that do not exist in the News table.

You might not be forming the constraint correctly. The column name "comment_id" sounds like the primary key to the Comments table. You want the foreign key, which matches the primary key of the News table. It might also be called "article_key" or "article_id".

```
    ALTER TABLE Comments
      ADD FOREIGN KEY( article_key)
        REFERENCES News( article_key);
```

If "comment_id" is really not the primary key of the "Comments" table, then the problem comes from not backing up and restoring both the News and Comments table at the same time.

You can either EXPORT and IMPORT the News table along with the Comments table, or remove the Comments that refer to missing News rows with something like this

```
    DELETE FROM Comments
      WHERE comments_id NOT IN (
        SELECT article_key
          FROM News
      )
```

Before you do this, you might want to try listing the Comments which would be deleted by the above query

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM Comments
      WHERE comments_id NOT IN (
        SELECT article_key
          FROM News
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've just discovered that when I perform step 5 before step 4, it somehow works, but I end up with the following error when doing a select * from comments
An error occurred while performing the operation:
Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table "NIWPS.NEWS_COMMENTS_COPY".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, DRIVER=3.57.82

Comment: It's the same reason. Something that you are importing (in comments.ixf) refers to a news row that does not exist. Can you answer these two questions? 1) What is the primary key of the News table (probably "article_id"). 2) Is there a column in Comments named "article_id"? (My guess is yes). If so, you need to use the ALTER TABLE statement I specified above. Change FOREIGN KEY(comments_id) to FOREIGN KEY(article_id)

Comment: Thanks, I realised what you meant. However, when I change comment_id to article_key in FOREIGN KEY, I get the same error when I did another select * from comments. Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table "NIWPS.COMMENTS".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, DRIVER=3.57.82 . To answer your questions above, Primary key is comment_id, not article_key (in other words, there is an article_key field in comments table but it's not a primary key) .

Comment: Is there a way for db2 to backup and restore just one single table only preserving referential integrity? Why is it so hard to do this? It's such a common requirement, why db2 cannot cater for this? Is this also a problem for other databases such as Oracle and SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem as well as my comments above,

1. user980717 resolved my first problem where I set the wrong column as the foreign key
2. For my 2nd issue, i.e. "SQL0668N Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table "tablename". SQLSTATE=57016", I need to run the following command "set integrity for niwps.comments immediate checked" to ensure data satisfied all constraints defined in the table. And thanks to all who took the effort in helping me with my problems. Cheers